# Adding dependency to multi module maven project in my application

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I have a multi-module library like:

```
pom.xml
    - module1 (results in jar1)
    - module2 (results in jar2)
```

I have another application where I need both these jars as dependencies. I am able to add two dependency with artifactId of module1 and module2.

Is there a way to add dependency to parent pom, so that both the jars are added.

Comment: If this helps ::  https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module, create a parent module for module1 and module2 then add that parent module dependency into your application.

Comment: @AshutoshMishra: I already have parent pom which has two modules (jar packaging). But the dependency to child modules (jar) are getting resolved but the dependency to parent pom (one with pom packaging) is not getting resolved. I want to add the parent (one with pom packaging) in my project and expect all the child modules (jars) to be automatically imported.

Comment: Short answer: No..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add a dependency directly to a parent POM to bring in the child modules as dependencies. The parent POM is generally used for managing shared configuration among child modules, and does not include or reference the artifacts produced by its child modules.

The usual way to handle this situation is, as you've already done, to add each module as a separate dependency in the application POM.

However, if you're trying to simplify dependency management, there are a few alternative solutions:

**Create an uber or shaded JAR:** Combine both modules into one jar file using Maven's Shade Plugin or similar. This new artifact can be used as a dependency, bringing in all classes from both modules. However, this could potentially lead to conflicts with other dependencies and it's a heavyweight solution for many situations.

**Create a BOM (Bill Of Materials):** A BOM is a special kind of POM that is used to control the versions of a project's dependencies and provide a central place to define and update those versions. The BOM can be imported in other projects to ensure consistent versioning of dependencies across multiple modules or projects.

**Aggregate artifact:** Create a new module that has dependencies on all other modules, and then depend on that new module. This only really makes sense if the modules have a tightly-coupled relationship, otherwise, it's not a great practice to group unrelated artifacts.

Remember, the right solution depends on your use case and the complexity of your project. You have to make sure that the solution you choose does not cause additional issues, such as version conflicts or unnecessarily large artifacts.
#chatgpt

Comment: Don't create shaded jar that will break overwrite via pom in your own project etc. The BOM only defines the versions but does not remove the requriment to define two dependencies....